# Wacky, weird colors when entering sculpt mode (blender v2.83)

Tags: mesh, color, sculpt

Every time I enter sculpt mode, the mesh (which should be grey) is a whole bunch of different colors. I tried changing the metacap, but the stupid colors remain. Any advice would be nice.

Picture bellow:

[image: Image of problem]

Comment: I've encountered this also, recently, in 2.83, and I couldn't find a pattern to explain why it is happening. I went researching it only to find no one talking about it. This leads me to believe it's a fairly new bug. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: Thank you. It's always nice to know I'm not the only one encountering the problem. My best bet is to downgrade to blender 2.82.

Comment: It happened to me too after joining different meshes together, a simple remesh fixed it

Comment: Might be something to do with face sets? - A new feature in 2.83 I believe. Check if it's turned on right at the bottom of the Viewport overlays menu. Alternatively, is 'Random' set as the viewport shading Colour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue for hours in Blender 2.9

It appears everytime I apply boolean modifier on two or more objects or when I join them. My assumption is that it might be because of different face densities.

The solution from John Eason is working for me. Just turn off the Face Sets.

[image]

Comment: In Blender 2.9 I had to go to sculpt mode, then there is a "Face Sets" menu in the top left corner of the viewport, click it, then hover over "Init Face Sets" then click "By Normals".

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem.