# Green faces in sculpt mode but I don't think I did anything

Tags: mesh, sculpting, topology

I was re-making an anvil following blender guru's tutorial(because I applied modifiers in wrong order and screw up without backup) but suddenly I saw gaping holes in my mesh and had a mini-panic and reverted back to my auto save. Then, I realized there are green faces where the holes were.

So, I thought maybe there are loose vertices or something so I went and looked in edit mode. But I couldn't find what was off about it.

I've tried to merge it by distance, smoothing it but it didn't do anything. I don't know why it's happening or what I've done wrong. But other side looks fine witch is making it more confusing.

I'm assuming it could be the multi-plane scrape tool, but other parts where I've used it are fine and I am stuck

[image: my mesh seems fine in edit mode]

**[image: but some of the faces look green]**

Answer (score 5):

I did a bit of searching and think I've found an answer.

[Wacky, weird colors when entering sculpt mode (blender v2.83)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183599/wacky-weird-colors-when-entering-sculpt-mode-blender-v2-83)

Basically, clock on the dropdown menu near the viewport mode selection, and deselect *'Face sets'* This should do the job.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would complete @Relevred answer proposing to do 'Alt-W > Face Set from Visible' which just seemed to reinitialise this state using all the object faces and so no need to turn off the overlay feature.

Docs:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/editing/face_sets.html